# Prewhitening / autocorrelation removal / AR(1) deterministic trend model

Tags: r

I am trying to prewhiten a time series using the methods described in a paper by K. Hamed found here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022169409000675

The idea is to fit an AR(1) model with a linear trend component to the data to remove the autocorrelation. The model I want to prewhiten with is given by

x_t = rho * x_(t-1) + alpha + beta * t + e_t

where x_t and x_(t-1) are observations of the time series, rho is the autocorrelation coefficient, beta is the slope of the trend and e_t is uncorrelated noise. Apologies for not knowing how to format equations, I tried to use Latex syntax to no avail...

Anyway I have estimated the parameters to be rho = 0.02, alpha = 0.16 and beta = -0.00092

How do I fit an AR(1) model in R given these specific parameter values? I thought using `init` in the `Arima` function would allow me to specify them but it just uses the input as *initial* values.

```
fit <- Arima(x, order=c(1,0,0),init=c(0.02, 0.16))
```

Furthermore, how do you fit a generic ARIMA model with a linear trend? I tried the following

```
for(t in 2:length(x)){
  fit <- Arima(x, order=c(1,0,0),init=c(0.02, 0.16)) - 0.00092 * t
}
```

but it returns an error as `non numeric argument to binary operator` and I am not sure how to work around this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `forecast::Arima` documentation:

```
Arima(x, order=c(0,0,0), seasonal=c(0,0,0),
    xreg=NULL, include.mean=TRUE, include.drift=FALSE, 
    include.constant, lambda=model$lambda, transform.pars=TRUE, 
    fixed=NULL, init=NULL, method=c("CSS-ML","ML","CSS"), n.cond, 
    optim.control=list(), kappa=1e6, model=NULL)
```

You have to include an external regressor (i.e. **linear trend**) as vector in xreg argument

`xreg   Optionally, a vector or matrix of external regressors, which must have the same number of rows as x.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer to the second part of my question. With regards to setting specific parameter values in the `Arima` function, I think I misunderstood the theory. As far as I know the `Arima` estimates the parameter values for me and so there is no method to input them to the function.